# error posting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to php and this is my first script:

```
function tinyf_users_add($name,$password,$email,$isadmin)
    {
      global $tf_handle;
      // define area
      $name = trim($name);
      $password = trim($password);
      $email = trim($email);
      $isadmin = trim($isadmin);
      $n_email= mysql_real_escape_string (strip_tags($email),$tf_handle);
      $n_pass = md5($password);
      $n_name = mysql_real_escape_string (strip_tags($name),$tf_handle);
      $n_iseadmin = abs(intval($isadmin));

      // check if not empty data
      if ((empty($name)) || (empty($password)) || (empty($email)) || (empty ($isadmin)))
          return false;
      else if (!filter_var($n_email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // check if valid email
          return false;
      else{
          $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (NULL, '%S', '%s', '%s', '%d')",$n_name,$n_pass,$n_email,$n_iseadmin);
          $qresult = mysql_query($query);
          if (!$qresult){
              return false;
          }
      else{
              return true;
          }
      }
    }
```

This is the add function but it's not working when i use the function for example

```
tinyf_users_add('yanal','ss','ss@ss.ss',0);
```

is not working

db connect code

```
<?php
  $tf_host = 'localhost'; 
  $tf_dbname = 'tinyforum'; 
  $tf_username = 'root'; 
  $tf_password = 'root'; 
  $tf_handle = @mysql_connect($tf_host,$tf_username,$tf_password);   
  if (!$tf_handle) 
    die('conn filad ');
  $tf_db_result = mysql_select_db($tf_dbname); 
  if (!$tf_db_result){
    die ('filed');
  } 
  @mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
  function tinyf_db_close()
  {
    global $tf_handle;
    @mysql_close($tf_handle);
  } 
?>
```

Comment: First remove all the `@` from your code, then tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: And try to return the $query from your function and do an echo $query to see if is valid

Comment: Typo in your sprintf, replace %S by %s

Comment: "its not working" is pretty vauge. **What part is not working?**

Comment: i'm calling the function to add user tinyf_users_add('yanal','ss','ss@ss.ss',0); but there's nothing aded

Comment: And the function doesn't return FALSE on a var_dump, does it? If so, it's getting stuck at other logic, which has `return false;`

Answer (score 2):

In your insert query you have forgot the `Values` clause add that:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (NULL, '%S', '%s', '%s', '%d')",$n_name,$n_pass,$n_email,$n_iseadmin);
                                     ^^^ add here
```

> NOTE: don't use the mysql_* as it has been deprecate.

Comment: i'm calling the function to add user tinyf_users_add('yanal','ss','ss@ss.ss',0);
but there's nothing aded to mysql

Comment: @YanalShmilan try this one $query = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (NULL, '$n_name', '$n_pass', '$n_email', '$n_iseadmin')";

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ same thing :(

Comment: removed i got white page

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is wrong.  You need to specify fields before the values:

Try this:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`) VALUES (NULL, '%S', '%s', '%s', '%d')",$n_name,$n_pass,$n_email,$n_iseadmin);
```

Comment: You don't ***need*** to, but it'll help with column count errors later on ;)

Comment: yes, assuming you want to use an auto-increment ID field... you kind of do really.. lol

Comment: Nope. If you're using an auto-increment field, you can put `NULL` as the value, and it'll still auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You have missed to add `values` in query

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`,`password`,`email`,`isadmin`) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%d')",
                 $n_name,
                 $n_pass,
                 $n_email,
                 $n_iseadmin);
$qresult = mysql_query($query, $tf_handle) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure here

Comment: id int , name text , password text , email text , isadmin int

Comment: @Yanal Shmilan I have updated the answer, can you please check

Comment: white page nothing on the database